# Selector para todos los elementos menos el primero

Tags: css, css3

Tengo 11 elementos p con la clase title **p.title**

¿ Cual sería el selector para añadir estilos a todos los **p.title** menos al primero ?

Podría seleccionar todos los demás con nth-child() y sus números pero no sería lo más eficiente

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Answer (score 17):

Puedes utilizar selector [:not(selector)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:not()) y filtrar con el selector [:first-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type).

```css
p.title:not(:first-of-type) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="title">Buenos días</p>
<p class="title">Buenas tardes</p>
<p class="title">Buenas noches</p>
```

> Ejemplos de uso de nth, first-child, first-of-type, etc... [Enlace](http://byverdu.es/css3-como-usar-los-selectores-de-las-pseudo-classes-nth-child-nth-of-type-y-not/)

Comment: Lo que buscaba, gracias

Comment: Si antes de todo eso tienes por ejemplo `<p>Buenas</p>` ya no funcionaría.

Comment: @blonfu ¿Cómo no funcionaría? No lo veo. Funcionaría correctamente, ya que autor de la pregunta busca cualquier **párrafo** con la clase *title* que no sea la primera. Tanto mi solución como la de Francisco Romero y Camilo Vasquez son correctas.

Comment: Digo si el primer párrafo no tuviera la clase title. Pero en las demás respuestas ocurriría igual, lo puse en esta porque tenia mas votos

Comment: @blonfu Correcto, no funcionaría si el párrafo no tuviera la clase title.

Comment: Al OP parece que le sirve porque su html seguramente sea similar has que has usado tú pero para ese caso el selector podría ser mas sencillo

Comment: @Rodrypaladin si te sirvió está repuesta o alguna de las otras debería marcarla como correcta. Veo que en ninguna de tus preguntas has marcado la respuesta que te sirvió, solo tienes que darle al check ✓ debajo del número de votos de la respuesta correcta

Answer (score 8):

***ACLARACIÓN*:** Mi respuesta original, no funcionará en casos en los que haya un párrafo (un elemento `<p>`) con una clase diferente a `title` (o sin clase) anterior al primer párrafo con clase `title`.

Para evitar esto, o para evitar que cualquier elemento que pongamos en medio de los párrafos con la clase `title` o sin clase "rompa" nuestro esquema, podremos usar el selector `~`.

Mediante el selector `~` podremos detectar todos los párrafos con clase `title` que estén precedidos por otro párrafo con clase `title`. De esta manera, el primer párrafo con clase `title` no será seleccionado ya que no estará precedido de ningún otro párrafo con dicha clase.

Ejemplo:

```css
p.title ~ p.title{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span>Prueba</span>
<p>Prueba</p>
<p class="otracosa">Prueba</p>
<p class="title">Esto es un texto</p>
<p class="title">Esto es un texto</p>
<p class="title">Esto es un texto</p>
<p>Prueba</p>
<span class="title">Prueba</span>
<p class="title">Esto es un texto</p>
<p class="title">Esto es un texto</p>
<p class="title">Esto es un texto</p>
<p class="title">Esto es un texto</p>
```

Como se puede observar, no afecta que haya párrafos sin clase (o con una clase diferente) delante del primer párrafo con clase `title` o que haya párrafos entre medio de los párrafos con dicha clase. Tampoco afecta que haya elementos distintos (en este caso he introducido un `span`) con la misma clase `title`.

---

***RESPUESTA ORIGINAL***

Podrías usar el selector `not` e indicar que no quieres que se apliquen los estilos para el primer elemento (`first-child`).

Ejemplo:

```css
p.title:not(:first-child){
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="title">Esto es un texto</p>
<p class="title">Esto es un texto</p>
<p class="title">Esto es un texto</p>
<p class="title">Esto es un texto</p>
<p class="title">Esto es un texto</p>
<p class="title">Esto es un texto</p>
<p class="title">Esto es un texto</p>
```

Answer (score 6):

Claro que puedes usar `:nth-child()`, debes usarlo de la siguiente forma para lograr lo que quieres:

```css
.title:nth-child(n + 2){
  color: chocolate;
}
```

```html
<p class="title">TITLE</p>
<p class="title">TITLE</p>
<p class="title">TITLE</p>
<p class="title">TITLE</p>
<p class="title">TITLE</p>
<p class="title">TITLE</p>
<p class="title">TITLE</p>
<p class="title">TITLE</p>
<p class="title">TITLE</p>
<p class="title">TITLE</p>
<p class="title">TITLE</p>
```

Answer (score 6):

Otra solución posible es usar el selector de hermano general `~`.

Si ponemos 
 `p.title ~ p.title` se seleccionan los párrafos con clase `title` que tengan un hemano previo que sea también un párrafo con clase `title`, por lo tanto el primer párrafo que tenga la clase `title` nunca se seleccionará. No afecta a párrafos sin clase `title` o a otros elementos que tengan también la clase `title`.

Un ejemplo para verlo en funcionamiento:

```css
p.title ~ p.title {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>párrafo sin clase title</p>
<p class="title">párrafo 1</p>
<p class="title">párrafo 2</p>
<p class="title">párrafo 3</p>
<div class="title">div con clase title</div>
<p class="title">párrafo  4</p>
<p class="title">párrafo 5</p>
<p class="title">párrafo 6</p>
<p class="title">párrafo 7</p>
<p class="title">párrafo 8</p>
<p class="title">párrafo 9</p>
<p class="title">párrafo 10</p>
<p class="title">párrafo 11</p>
```

Comment: Después de buscar durante un buen rato un selector que pudiera hacer esto y actualizar mi respuesta, me acabo de dar cuenta de que he puesto la misma solución que tú (y creo que la única posible actualmente). No sé que se haría en este tipo de casos :S

Comment: @FranciscoRomero. Yo creo que es una buena solución y bastante sencilla, tu respuesta anterior y las de los demás sirven para el caso concreto del OP pero el selector de hermanos abarca casi todas (o todas) las posibilidades.

Comment: Sí, yo he estado trasteando con varias posibilidades y con ninguna me ha dado error. Creo que es la que más se adapta a las necesidades del OP. Yo me refería al hecho de que fuera la misma solución repetida en ambos (aunque haya dejado la original).

Comment: @FranciscoRomero suele pasar llegar a la misma solución y a veces no darse cuenta que ya estaba. No tengo ningún problema con eso, de hecho igual acabaré borrando mi respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Esta es otra alternativa...

Escoges primero todos los elementos y posteriormente "deseleccionas el primero" para darle otra propiedad CSS

```
.menugrislista li a:hover 
{
color: crimson
}
          
.menugrislista li:nth-of-type(1) a
{
color: #fff ;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="menugrislista">
<li><a href="#">Corporativo</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Tienda Yamaha</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Fundación</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Musical</a></li>
<li><a href="#">POrtal Distribuidores</a></li>
</ul>
```